# My Answer has met the criteria for the Maverick hat. Yet, I have no hat

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2016

[More efficient way to clean a column of strings and add a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41269644/2336654)

Was a -3 question in which I answered and has subsequently become a 3+ question along with my answer becoming 5+.

Are there other criteria that aren't listed?  Is it possible the periodic criteria checker has skipped it for some reason?

Comment: That's weird... maybe caching?

Comment: The [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41269644/timeline) shows only two downvotes, but there might be another one which was retracted on the same day.

Comment: @Glorfindel On the same day you say?  Yeah, that was probably mine.  I downvoted, then edited, then upvoted.  Is that something that you'd think is not in the spirit of the criteria?  If so, I'll try again.  But I thought by the letter of the "law" I nailed it.

Comment: @piRSquared I don't know, I'm just pointing to a possible cause.

Comment: @Glorfindel I get it, and I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the timeline, that question had a total of zero votes on it at the time you posted your answer. The three downvotes came in later, one of which was yours that you retracted. However, the hat is not for just having an answer on a -3 question that becomes +3 - the answer needs to be posted *after* it was already at -3. The theory of the hat is that your answer turned the question around, similar to the Reversal badge. Your answer there would have never qualified for the hat regardless of the votes that came in later.

Comment: That makes sense. And now I know!

Answer (score 3):

Ah, because it was never reached -3 in the first place (I'm talking about the question). If you can see its vote counts, it says +7/-2:

[image]

Probably by the time the hat checker came by, someone retracted their downvote so the lowest it can possibly be is actually `-2`. Since the question needs to be at -3 at one point, you couldn't get the hat.

Comment: !BaH!  Your are probably right.  And that was my vote that was retracted as well.  So I didn't let it sit at -3 long enough

Comment: @piRSquared Well fooled yourself eh

Comment: Yes!  I certainly did.

Comment: Oh! I will ;-).  4 minutes or so